# Javascript charting API that support multiple grouped data

Tags: javascript, charts

Can anyone recommend an API that will support multiple groupings in the data? What I mean by that is along the X axis I need to have a group, which contains a number of groups, which each contain a further number of groups which then contain 3 data items.

I have spent hours looking but at the moment I cant seem to find anything that can show this sort of data.

To try and further explain what it is I need to show in case it isnt very clear imagine I wanted to show County, for each County I want to show a number of schools and for each school two tests (Math, English)  and then for each test at each school the male and female average test score.

So far I have only been able to find api's that support standard column charts with a single X axis label.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: keep it simple. The exact chart you're looking for probably doesn't exist because it's so specific. Pick something that comes close.

You can always do the grouping visually, by colour. I've found Google Charts API to be quite usable. If you use the dynamic JavaScript variant you can make charts with as many data points as you like, of any dimension.

Comment: Other alternatives: [Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/overview/index.html), [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I need to show this as its a requirement so probably means I will have to adapt something... I looked at high charts and it doesnt support this, Kendo UI looks nicer but it also doesnt support it. I will have a look at the google api now.

Comment: Maybe you can find useful the treemap from google chart tools. AFAIK you can put several levels of depth. Maybe the way of representation fits your needs.